# Is there is any way to check user is subscribed to my youtube channel or not

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, vue.js, youtube

Is there is any way to check user is subscribed to my youtube channel or not ? (Php Laravel vuejs 2 SPA)

Answer (score 0):

you should refer youtube api : https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time no. If they set their subscriptions to public, it will notify you when they subscribe, and there is a list in your youtube studio.
If they turn it off (usually people do) then you have no idea.